# How to execute a command line program in Firefox Webextensions?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'd like to run a command (exe somewhere on disk) with arguments in a simple WebExtensions addon, and possibly get its stdout. Is there a way to do so in WebExtensions, since the older APIs are being deprecated?

Answer (score 5):

This blog post mentions how - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/06/09/webextensions-for-firefox-49/

Read the section `runtime.connectNative`. They say:

> runtime.connectNative
>
> This API allows you to communicate with other processes on the host’s operating system. It’s a commonly used API for password managers and security software which needs to communicate with external processes.
>
> To communicate with a native process, there’s a two-step process. First, your installer needs to install a JSON manifest file at an appropriate file location on the target computer. That JSON manifest provides the link between Firefox and the process. Secondly, the user installs the add-on. Then the add-on can call the connectNative, sendNativeMessage and other APIs:
>
> ```
> chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('your-application',
>   { text: "Hello" },
>   function(response) {
>     console.log("Received " + response);
> });
> ```
>
> Firefox will start the process if it hasn’t started already, and pipe commands through to the process. Follow along with the progress of runtime.connectNative on Bugzilla.

Comment: Since the blog lists this API as "in progress" I'm guessing it can't be used right now?

Comment: @MichaelBednarek probably can only be used in Nightly and Dev Edition. If you want to make a Firefox Addon SDK addon though, you can use `child_process` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process